Getting the mean and median age of an age class
From the population below:
    0-9 10-19   20-29   30-39   40-49   50-59   60-69   70-79   80-89   90-99   100-109 110-119
Male    -692    -772    -741    -698    -707    -511    -371    -203    -95 -17 -8  -1.0
Female  676 771 808 865 815 581 400 226 102 15  8   0.0

I want to plot a an age pyramid and also compute the mean and median age class of the population
I was manually able to get a pyramid using below pandas dataframe
age_p = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [ '100+', '90-99', '80-89', '70-79', '60-69', '50-59', '40-49', '30-39', '20-29', '10-19', '0-9'],
'Male': [-9, -17, -95, -203, -371, -511, -707, -698, -741, -772, -692],
'Female': [8, 15, 102, 226, 400, 581, 815, 865, 808, 771, 676]})

AgeClass = ['100+', '90-99', '80-89', '70-79', '60-69', '50-59', '40-49', '30-39', '20-29', '10-19', '0-9']

I feel like this could be less manual and more pythonic

take a look at pandas cut https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Starting from your age_p, start by setting "Age" as index, then sort_index using the last number as key (obtained with  str.extract and converted to integer), then plot.barh with stacked=True:
tmp = (age_p
 .set_index('Age')
 .sort_index(key=lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)\+?$', expand=False).astype(int))
)
tmp.plot.barh(stacked=True)

Output:

For the average age, and considering 100+ as 100, you can use a weighted average:
avg_bin = tmp.index.str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].unstack('match').astype(float).mean(axis=1)
avg_age = np.average(np.broadcast_to(avg_bin.to_numpy()[:, None], tmp.shape),
                     axis=0, weights=tmp.abs())

Output: array([34.35247093, 35.17476742])

in the first part build age pyrmid.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

age_classes = ['100+', '90-99', '80-89', '70-79', '60-69', '50-59', '40-49', '30-39', '20-29', '10-19', '0-9']
male_counts = [-9, -17, -95, -203, -371, -511, -707, -698, -741, -772, -692]
female_counts = [8, 15, 102, 226, 400, 581, 815, 865, 808, 771, 676]

age_p = pd.DataFrame({'Age': age_classes, 'Male': male_counts, 'Female': female_counts})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x_range= np.arange(len(age_classes))
bar_width = 0.35

male_bars = ax.barh(x_range- bar_width/2, male_counts, bar_width, label='Male')
female_bars = ax.barh(x_range- bar_width/2, female_counts, bar_width, label='Female')

ax.set_xlabel('Population Count')
ax.set_ylabel('Age')
ax.set_yticks(x_range)
ax.set_yticklabels(age_classes)
ax.legend()

plt.title('Age Pyramid')
plt.show()

In the second part, we need to calculate the mean and the median age for your data frame. However, in the Male Column, we have a minus value we have to you abs to get the correct value, and other problem is "100+"  so create if statement to handle that. So, the final version of the code for the calculation of median and mean age is shown below.  I hope it can help you to understand.
age_values = []
for age_class in age_classes:
    if '+' in age_class:
        age_values.append(float(age_class[:-1]) + 0.5)  # Handling '100+' as a special case
    else:
        age_range = age_class.split('-')
        age_values.append((int(age_range[0]) + int(age_range[1])) / 2)

age_counts = np.abs(np.array(male_counts)) + np.array(female_counts) 

mean_age_class = np.average(age_values, weights=age_counts)
median_age_class = np.median(np.repeat(age_values, np.abs(age_counts)))

